# Maintaining navigation animation in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

A `UITableViewController` in iOS includes a subtle animation for row selection whereby on returning to a view (via the back button) the previously-selected row is briefly highlighted. This affords the user a sense of location in the app.

For `UIViewController`s, this behavior doesn't come for free. The simple way to include is manually deselect the selected row in `viewWillAppear`.

However, iOS 7 allows the user to 'drag' backwards through the navigation stack. Partially dragging but then not completing the drag action will fire `viewWillAppear` and deselect the row. When the user returns for real, the row is not selected.

Using `viewDidAppear` will certainly resolve this issue, but the animation is triggered later (obviously) and makes the app feel sluggish.

Has anyone come up with a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking on a solution for this myself. When you look at the behavior of the native mail app implementation for instance, if you click on the back button, the deselection animation starts before `viewDidAppear`, but it is not in `viewWillAppear` either, because then the animation is very fast and abrupt when not interactively dismissing. However, when you do interactively dismissing and deselect on `viewWillAppear`, the cell is gradually deselected along with the finger gesture, like the native mail application. It seems `viewWillAppear` is called internally within an animation block.
From experimentation, `performSelector:@selector(deselect) afterDelay:0` in `viewWillAppear` yields the desired animation when clicking back animation.

So to summarize, when user taps back button: `performSelector:@selector(deselect) afterDelay:0` in `viewWillAppear`; when the user interactively swipes to dismiss, `deselect` in `viewWillAppear`.

So how to distinguish between the two cases? Certainly not enough information in `viewWillAppear`.
Now, one could, implement the navigation controller delegate methods, signal the table view controller that an interactive pop is about to start (before `viewWillAppear`) and then hand it to Apple's regular interactive pop interaction controller. The catch? `_interactionController` is private API. Silly silly Apple.

I then discovered that you can feed the `UINavigationController` to its `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`. So you can sit in the middle, listen to delegate methods, signal your table view controller and call apple's implementation of the delegate for the gesture recognizer.

This should be enough to get you going. Perhaps an optional protocol and category above `UITableViewController`, and then test if the popped to table view controller instance responds to the signal method. Or a subclass, of course.